# Tauri + Angular 16 Drag And Drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, tauri

I have been trying to implement simple html drag and drop into tauri + angular but I cannot get it to work. I only need a basic drag and drop.

Only the dragstart event fires. dragover and drop does not and I cannot find why.

Here is my component:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    greetingMessage = "";

    onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("drag over", event);
    }

    onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("drop event", event);
    }

    onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
        console.log("drag started", event);
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div id="dropzone" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)"> DROP HERE</div>

<img draggable="true" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="a draggable image" (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)">
```

I tried not using angular's events and rather the default ones (ondragstart, ondrop, etc) and it would not work either. Whereas it would work in a plain html file.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I found out it was coming from the tauri config file:

For drag and drop to work you have to disable the "fileDropEnabled" field which is on true by default.

From the docs:

## WindowConfig

### fileDropEnabled

> Whether the file drop is enabled or not on the webview. By default it is enabled.
>
> Disabling it is required to use drag and drop on the frontend on Windows.

tauri.conf.json

```json
{
    "tauri": {
        "windows": [
            {
                "fileDropEnabled": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

app.component.html

```
      <div id="dropzone" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)"> DROP HERE</div>
      <img
      draggable="true"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
      alt="a draggable image"
      (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)"
    >
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'draganddrop';
      greetingMessage = "";
    
        onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
            console.log("drag started", event);
        }
        onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("drag over", event);
      }
    
      onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("drop event", event);
    
        const dropZone = event.target as HTMLElement;
    
        if (dropZone.id === 'dropzone') {
            const imageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';
            const droppedElement = document.createElement('img');
            droppedElement.src = imageUrl;
            droppedElement.alt = 'a dropped image';
            droppedElement.style.height = '200px';
            dropZone.appendChild(droppedElement);
        }
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem came from tauri and not angular. I added an answer to my post. After changing the config file for tauri and disabling `fileDropEnabled`, both code started to work.